# Два select и Post значение

Tags: laravel, post, select

Задача сделать два select  для панели поиска , с задачей справился - при выборе select(model) появляется второй select(device) с доступными устройствами. При выборе устройства и отправке формы  получается что второй  не соответствует выбранному значению.
В браузере получается следующее :

```
<div class="search-panel" style="font-size: 24px;" >
    <form id="search-box" method="Post" action="/phone/get_table">
       <div class="search-box">
        Выберете устройство :
            <select id="select1" name="model">
               <option id="opt" value="1" onClick="showhide(1)">Apple</option>
               <option id="opt" value="3" onClick="showhide(3)">Nokia</option>
               <option id="opt" value="4" onClick="showhide(4)">HTC</option>
               <option id="opt" value="8" onClick="showhide(8)">Alcatel</option>
               <option id="opt" value="10" onClick="showhide(10)">LG</option>
               <option id="opt" value="11" onClick="showhide(11)">Meizu</option>
               <option id="opt" value="13" onClick="showhide(13)">Philips</option>
               <option id="opt" value="16" onClick="showhide(16)">ZTE</option>
                            </select>
       <div id="1" style="display: none;" >
                  <select name="device">
                        <option value="1">iPhone 6</option>
                        <option value="3">iPhone 5s</option>
                        <option value="7">iPhone 6s</option>
                        <option value="10">IPhone 4</option>
                        <option value="12">IPhone 6 plus</option>
                 </select>
        </div>


        <div id="3" style="display: none;" >
                 <select name="device">
                        <option value="0">[--все--]</option>
                  </select>
        </div>


       <div id="4" style="display: none;" >
                <select name="device">
            <option value="4">HTC One M8</option>
            <option value="13">Другие</option>
                </select>
       </div>

   <!--.....-->
        <div id="8" style="display: none;" >
               <select name="device">
                        <option value="0">[--все--]</option>
                </select>
        </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="brand" value ="1">
         <button class="btn" href="#">Найти</button>
        </div>
            </form>
     </div>
<!--javascript-->
  <script type="application/javascript">
    var divState = {};
    function showhide(id) {
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var divid = document.getElementById(id);
            divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true;
            //close others
            for (var div in divState){
                if (divState[div] && div != id){
                    document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
                    divState[div] = false;
                }
            }
            divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'inline-block' ? 'none' : 'inline-block');
        }
    }
</script>
```

на php это выглядит следующим образом :

```
<div class="search-panel" style="font-size: 24px;" >
        <form id="search-box" method="Post" action="/{{$url}}/get_table">
        <div class="search-box">
        Выберете устройство :
            <select id="select1" name="model">
            @foreach($model as $dev)
                    <option id="opt" value="{{ $dev->id }}" onClick="showhide({{ $dev->id }})">{{ $dev->title }}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
                @foreach($model as $dev)
            <?php $devicemodel =\App\DeviceModel::checkDM($brand->id,$dev->id);?>
                <div id="{{$dev->id}}" style="display: none;" >
                @if($devicemodel)
                <select name="device">
            @foreach($devicemodel as $dev)
                    @if($dev)
                        <?php  $name =\App\DeviceModel::returnName($dev->device_id)?>
                       <option value="{{$dev->device_id}}">{{$name->title}}</option>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                </select>
                @else
                    <select name="device">
                        <option value="0">[--все--]</option>
                    </select>
                @endif
                        </div>


                @endforeach
            <input type="hidden" name="brand" value ="{{ $brand->id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <button class="btn" href="#">Найти</button>
        </div>
            </form>
     </div>
```

Возможно дело в том что куча select с именем device  и вы выводим то что нам надо  изменяя свойство display:none , но если  изменить имя на например на device_{{$dev->device_id}} как я получу это в POST ? Заранее спасибо .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простите пожалуйста, но ваш код никуда не годится.

Сперва, обратим внимание на то, как вы обрабатываете событие выбора в первом селекте model. onclick в данном случае использовать не только неудобно (к каждому option нужно дописывать соответствующий вызов функции в аттрибуте onclick) и некрасиво, но и абсолютно неправильно! Ведь выбор осуществляется не только кликом мыши. Я, к примеру, по долгу службы больше уважаю клавиатуру и предпочитаю перемещаться по формам, используя TAB и выбор в селекте произвожу, зачастую, стрелками с последующим нажатием enter. Ваша форма меня не поймет и не покажет второе поле.

Гораздо более правильно, со всех сторон, использовать событие `change`, срабатывающее на элементе `select` в момент выбора. Никаких аттрибутов у потомков, всего один слушатель события в js-коде.

Далее: как вы правильно заметили, дело именно в том, что у вас в форме куча элементов с одинаковым `name`. При отправке формы браузер, грубо говоря, собирает массив, куда складывает под ключи - `name` - значения полей. Если полей с одинаковым `name` несколько - каждое следующее будет затирать значение предыдущего (в массив под один и тот же ключ раз за разом добавляются новые значения) и в итоге останется только последнее значение.

Не нужно создавать на странице кучу селектов с одинаковым `name`. Нужно создать только один и в нем, при выборе первого селекта, перегенеривать список `option`. Или, все же, можно создать кучу готовых селектов, но с пустым `name` и добавлять его нужному селекту вместе с его отображением, убирая `name` у всех остальных. Но мне ближе, все же, первый вариант. Он чище и прозрачнее, на мой взгляд.

Теперь я предлагаю вам ознакомиться с упрощенным кодом, в котором я попытаюсь продемонстрировать вам, как нужно реализовать вашу задачу:

```js
//в js на загрузке страницы создадим объект, в котором под id производителя разложим списки устройств 
var devicesByModel = {
  //здесь "1" - id производителя, в данном случае - "Apple"
  1: {
    //здесь "1" - будущее value для option, "iPhone 6" - его текст
    1: "iPhone 6",
    3: "iPhone 5s",
    7: "iPhone 6s",
    10: "IPhone 4"
  },
  3: {
    1: "3310",
    2: "8110",
    3: "8310",
    4: "6310"
  },
  4: {
    1: "ONE M7",
    2: "ONE M8",
    3: "ONE M9",
    4: "TWO"
  }
};

//выбираем селект по его id и вешаем слушателя события change
document.getElementById('modelSelect').addEventListener('change', function(){
  
  var value = this.value,
      devicesList = devicesByModel[value],
      deviceSelect = document.getElementById('deviceSelect');
  
  //если в нашем массиве есть девайсы по выбранному производителю
  if(devicesList){
    var options = "";
    //идем по списку девайсов и на каждом создаем очередной option с соответствующими значениями
    for(var deviceId in devicesList){
      options += '<option value="'+deviceId+'">'+devicesList[deviceId]+'</option>';
    }
    //заменяем список option внутри device-select'а на только что сгенереный
    deviceSelect.innerHTML = options;    
    deviceSelect.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    //эта часть нужна только в случае, если у model-selecta можно снять выбор
    deviceSelect.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="modelSelect" name="model">
  <option id="opt" value="">Выберите производителя...</option>
  <option id="opt" value="1">Apple</option>
  <option id="opt" value="3">Nokia</option>
  <option id="opt" value="4">HTC</option>
</select>

<select id="deviceSelect" name="device" style="display:none">
  <!--пока пусто. сгенерируем список options после выбора в селекте name=model-->
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо , понял . Я с js толком не имел дело . Попробую разобраться.

Comment: @KonstantinMaslov если ответ вам помог и является верным - подтвердите это нажатием кнопки слева от ответа. Так же, можно выразить благодарность автору поставив ответу +1.