# В форме есть 2 select нужно в POST передать значение только одного

Tags: php, form, select, smarty

Задача - 2 списка (данные берутся из бд из 1-й таблицы со списком тем и описанием с уникальным id), которые переключаются в зависимости от выбранной кнопки (не обязательно input radio), и отсылается в POST значение только отображаемого списка.

Код:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="cheker" id="cheker1"/>
    <span>Заявка </span>
<input type="radio" name="cheker" id="cheker2"/>
    <span>Возврат </span>

<div class="select vozvrat">
    <select name="theme">
        {foreach name=questions from=$questions key=id item=theme}
            {if $theme.group == '1'};
                <option value="{$theme.id}">{$theme.theme_text}</option>
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
    </select>
</div>
<div class="select zayavka">
    <select name="theme">
        {foreach name=questions from=$questions key=id item=theme}
            {if $theme.group == '2'};
                <option value="{$theme.id}">{$theme.theme_text}</option>
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
    </select>
</div>
```

css радио-кнопок:

```
#cheker2:checked ~ .zayavka {display: none;}

#cheker1:checked ~ .vozvrat {display: none;}
```

Списки отображаются в зависимости от выбранного переключателя.

При отправке формы в POST вне зависимости от выбранного значения в любом из списков отправляется первое значение {$theme.id} из второго select.

{$theme.group} просто группирует значения из таблицы по 1 и 2 группам.

Другими словами, сначала в theme записывается значение первого списка, а далее сразу переписывается из 2-го.

Киньте ссылкой на пример с 2-мя селектами, или намекните как правильно в гугле забить))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Верного примера решения именно с вашим кодом вы не найдете. У вас изначально неправильно построена верстка, не должно быть в рамках одной формы два элемента с одинаковым именем, однако у вас есть именно два элемента с одним и тем же именем `theme`. Варианта решения тут может быть два:

1. Вы изменяете имена элементов и соответствующим образом изменяете свой код под это дело, как на фронте так и в бекенде.
2. Вы изменяете код фронта таким образом, чтобы одновременно у вас был только один элемент с указанным именем. Это можно реализовать не **скрывая / показывая** нужный элемент по значению другого, а **добавляя / удаляя** их в код страницы (но тут уже чистым `css` не обойдешься). Таким образом ничто ничего не будет перезаписывать, равно как и с точки зрения стандартов у браузеров не будет претензий к вашему коду, так как в форме не будет сразу двух элементов с одинаковым именем.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно будет кому полезно, нашел решение на js в ответе [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552624/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0-select-%D0%B8-post-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) где 2-х уровневый select вместо переключателя radio.